# CSS to have content on center and something on right of the div

Tags: html, css

How can I have content on the center and an icon on the right of the div. This currently gives something like this:

[image]

But I want it to be like this:

[image]

Notice in the above 50% is in the center of `div` and `pencil` icon is on the right.

```css
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-100">
  <p>{value}</p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, please tag the appropriate version. FYI, there's a typo in your icon tag. This isn't a React question.

Comment: I know two ways, the first is using empty span with display flex and justify content space between, or give the div text align center and the icon float right but you'll get some issues when the div size goes short

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically align text next to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image)

Comment: @OmarZaoujal, answers go down there. Please take the [tour] if you need a refresher.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this 2 ways:

- The standard flexbox approach. Use align-items: center to put the text in the middle **but** there's a gotcha in that if there are two items stacked on top of each other and the icon on the top one is 50 pixels wide and the next below one is 80 pixels wide then the center-aligned element may not be aligned on top of each other correctly.
- To make sure your element is 100% placed in the middle, use 3 divs, with flex-grow: 1 to make 3 equally wide containers then use margins to position the child elements to the center or right.

Also have a look at a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988462/text-always-in-middle-of-screen-dynamically/73989538#73989538) on stackoverflow

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.container>div:nth-child(2)>p {
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.container>div:last-child>img {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <p>50%</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='https://placekitten.com/50/50' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for this...

```css
.w-100 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-icon {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-100">
  <p>{value}</p>
  <img class='img-icon' src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` on parent element and `flex-grow: 1` on the element you want to stretch.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

p {
  text-align:center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>50%</p>
  <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mono-general-2/24/edit-icon.png" width="24" height="24" />
</div>
```